# Is HTTP 303 acceptable for other HTTP methods?

Tags: http, rest, http-status-codes, http-redirect, http-status-code-303

[RESTful Web Services](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529260.do) encourages the use of [HTTP 303](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.4) to redirect clients to the canonical representation of a resource. It only discusses topic in the context of `HTTP GET`.

Does this apply to other HTTP methods as well? If a client attempts a `HTTP PUT` or `DELETE` to a non-canonical URI, is it acceptable (and/or recommended) to return HTTP 303? What is the best practice and why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> This status code is generally applicable to any HTTP method. It is primarily used to allow the output of a POST action to redirect the user agent to a selected resource, since doing so provides the information corresponding to the POST response in a form that can be separately identified, bookmarked, and cached independent of the original request.

**Source**: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-21#section-7.4.4

Comment: Further proof: http://trac.tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/trac/ticket/310 -- IETF explicitly removed references to `HTTP GET` in response to a `HTTP 303`. See also: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/08/19/understanding-the-impact-of-redirect-response-status-codes-on-http-methods-like-head-get-post-and-delete.aspx

Answer (score 6):

I just discovered an interesting section in the book. According to page 378 section `302 ("Found")`:

> This status code is the ultimate source of most redirection-related confusion. It’s supposed to be handled just like 307 (“Temporary Redirect”). In fact, in HTTP 1.0 its name
>   was “Moved Temporarily.” Unfortunately, in real life most clients handle 302 just like
>   303 (“See Other”). The difference hinges on what the client is supposed to do when it
>   gets a 302 in response to a **PUT, POST, or DELETE** request. See the entry for 307 below
>   if you’re interested in the details.
>
> To resolve this ambiguity, in HTTP 1.1 this response code was renamed to “Found,”
>   and response code 307 was created.

In other words, HTTP 302 was split into HTTP 303 and 307.
Next, on page 380 section `307 ("Temporary Redirect")`:

> For GET requests, where the only thing being requested is that the server send a representation, this status code is identical to 303 (“See Other”). A typical case where 307
>   is a good response to a GET is when the server wants to send a client to a mirror site.
>   But for **POST, PUT, and DELETE requests**, where the server is expected to take some
>   action in response to the request, this status code is significantly different from 303.
>
> A 303 in response to a **POST, PUT, or DELETE** means that the operation has succeeded
>   but that the response entity-body is not being sent along with this request. If the client
>   wants the response entity-body, it needs to make a GET request to another URI.
>   A 307 in response to a POST, PUT, or DELETE means that the server has not even tried
>   to perform the operation. The client needs to resubmit the entire request to the URI in
>   the `Location` header.

In other words, **HTTP POST, PUT, DELETE are legal on HTTP 303, 307**. The above paragraph explains the expected behavior.

That being said, I'm quoting the book here, not the HTTP specification (which is suspiciously silent on the expected behavior).

Comment: It's not so much that it's designed for it, so much as the PRC pattern came about due to the way that browsers treated the response code, and the behaviour became a de facto standard.

Comment: @KeithGaughan, I just ran across an answer in the book that sheds new light on the specification. See my updated answer.